# TypeError: $scope.phraseDetail.forEach is not a function when trying to find matches in a single item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I keep getting the following error message: `TypeError: $scope.phraseDetail.forEach is not a function` each time I try to find matches and replace text in a single item.

The code below works perfect when [iterating over multiple items in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623961/iterate-over-items-in-object-find-matches-and-replace), i.e. when the API output is as follows:

*/api/phrases/*

```
[
    {
        "id": "f40e0e47-6457-463b-a5f9-9dc97bd2d0ce",
        "phrase": "Training {{group}} to develop their {{attribute}} by ensuring they are comfortable with {{factor}}"
    },
    {
        "id": "66314a72-07ae-445c-97c0-4f659387bbb2",
        "phrase": "Assisting {{person}} in strength and conditioning work to improve {{factor}}"
    }
]
```

However it does not work when there is only a single item being returned, i.e. as follows:

*api/phrases/f40e0e47-6457-463b-a5f9-9dc97bd2d0ce/*

```
{
    "id": "f40e0e47-6457-463b-a5f9-9dc97bd2d0ce",
    "phrase": "Training {{group}} to develop their {{attribute}} by ensuring they are comfortable with {{factor}}"
}
```

How can I fix this? I have included my code below:

**phrase-detail.html** (note: bind-html-compile is a directive I nabbed from https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile)

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item item-text-wrap item-line-height" bind-html-compile="phraseDetail.phrase"></div>
</div>
```

**controllers.js**

```
function PhraseDetailCtrl($scope, $stateParams, PhrasesService, FilterService, $ionicLoading, $timeout) {

        $ionicLoading.show({
            content: 'Loading',
            animation: 'fade-in',
            showBackdrop: true,
            maxWidth: 200,
            showDelay: 0
        });


        $timeout(function () {

            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $scope.dataLoaded = true;
            $scope.phraseId = $stateParams.phraseId;

            PhrasesService.getPhrasesDetail($scope.phraseId).then(function(dataResponse) {
                $scope.phraseDetail = dataResponse.data;

                var replacers = FilterService.getItemFilter();

                $scope.phraseDetail.forEach(function(e){
                    Object.keys(replacers).forEach(function(key){
                        e['phrase'] = e['phrase'].replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), replacers[key]);
                    })
                })
            })

        }, 1000)


        $scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
             $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Toggle!' : 'some text';
     })

    }
```

**services.js**

```
/**
*
*/
function PhrasesService($http) {

    this.getPhrasesDetail = function (phraseId) {

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: server + '/api/phrases/' + phraseId,
        });

    }

}



/**
*
*/
function FilterService() {

    this.getItemFilter = function () {

        var replacers = {
            '{{group}}' : '<div class="button button-small button-outline button-positive button-side-padding">group</div>',
            '{{attribute}}' : '<div class="button button-small button-outline button-assertive button-side-padding">attribute</div>',
            '{{factor}}' : '<div class="button button-small button-outline button-assertive button-side-padding">factor</div>',
            '{{person}}' : '<div class="button button-small button-outline button-positive button-side-padding">person</div>'
        }

        return replacers;

    }

}
```

Comment: first response is array, second is object...

Comment: Thanks. So I presume the issue lies here: http://pastebin.com/feQXEKpK in `PhraseDetailCtrl`. How would I rewrite this bit of code to make it work?